# In python 2.4, how can I execute external commands with csh instead of bash?

Tags: python, shell, csh, tcsh

Without using the new 2.6 subprocess module, how can I get either os.popen or os.system to execute my commands using the tcsh instead of bash?  I need to source some scripts which are written in tcsh before executing some other commands and I need to do this within python2.4.

EDIT
Thanks for answers using 'tcsh -c', but I'd like to avoid this because I have to do escape madness.  The string will be interpreted by bash and then interpreted by tcsh.  I'll have to do something like:

```
os.system("tcsh -c '"+re.compile("'").sub(r"""'"'"'""",my_cmd)+"'")
```

Can't I just tell python to open up a 'tcsh' sub-process instead of a 'bash' subprocess?  Is that possible?

P.S.
I realize that bash is the cat's meow, but I'm working in a corporate environment and I'm going to choose to *not* fight a tcsh vs bash battle -- bigger fish to fry.

Comment: what do you mean by "source"?

Comment: If you execute a command like 'source env_mod.csh' the script will modify your current shell.  If you do 'tcsh -f env_mod.csh' the shell script will create a child shell that inherits the environment variables of your current shell and execute without modifying the parent shell.

Comment: Example includes your ~/.bashrc file which gets 'sourced' when you start a new bash shell.

Comment: i know that, i just wasn't sure about _where_ you actually wanted to source something -- from within os.system() or from a shell script you call with os.system()...

Comment: There are many Electronic Design Automation CAD tools (e.g. Specman, VManager, VCS, NCSim) which provide an env.csh which you source to setup your PATH, license server, env pointers to different pieces.  Basically I want to source those env setup files and then execute a command.

Comment: e.g. os.system('source $SPECMAN_HOME/env.csh -64bit && specman -c "load foo.e; write stubs -vcssv"')<BR>


The problem is that os.system executes bash and I need tcsh because that's what everyone uses at my company.

Answer (score 11):

Just prefix the shell as part of your command. I don't have tcsh installed but with zsh:

```
>>> os.system ("zsh -c 'echo $0'")
zsh
0
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
>>> os.system("tcsh your_own_script")
```

Or just write the script and add

```
#!/bin/tcsh
```

at the beginning of the file and let the OS take care of that.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the shell to use to be `tcsh`:

```
>>> os.environ['SHELL'] = 'tcsh'
>>> os.environ['SHELL']
'tcsh'
>>> os.system("echo $SHELL")
tcsh
```

Comment: Doesn't work:
    % bash
    bash-3.00$ echo $SHELL
    tcsh
    bash-3.00$

    >>> import os
    >>> print os.environ['SHELL']
    tcsh
    >>>

Comment: anyway, the shell that os.system executes is bash even if you set $SHELL to tcsh

Comment: nice try... but shell don't conform to duck typing